# Why do men have a greater chance of suffering from hair loss?

Tags: human-biology, hair

If we look around we'll find that men are more likely to suffer from hair loss when compared to women. Is there is any specific reason for this?

Comment: some hair loss is related to testosterone, as to why eununchs tend to preserve hair better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_hair_loss      (article about eununchs)        http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20131127-will-we-ever-banish-baldness

Comment: @RoSiv Please make an answer rather than posting an answer in the comments.

Comment: @BryanKrause      I wasnt really confidant with my answer but ok.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, some types of [hair loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_hair_loss) is androgenic, and therefore related to testosterone levels. This is why eunuchs can be [resistant](http://%20bbc.com/future/story/20131127-will-we-ever-banish-baldness) to some forms of hair loss.